# NSNotification Not Being Sent

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsnotificationcenter

I am using **NSNoficationCenter** to pass the value of an array from one **ViewConroller** to another.

**ViewControllerB** is a subview of **ViewController A**

In **ViewController A** i have a method which takes an array as the argument, once the method receives the array I am using the the following code to store the value of the array

```
-(void)gettingValueOfArray:(NSArray*)newArray{

 NSDictionary *storeArray = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:newArray,@"newArray", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loadArray" object:self userInfo:storeArray];

}
```

In **ViewController B**  i use the following to receive the notification in the **viewDidLoad**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadArray:) name:@"loadArray" object:nil];

}
```

and then use this method to save the value of array

```
-(void)saveArray:(NSNotification *)notfication{

NSArray *saveValueOfArray = [notification userinfo]objectForKey:@"newArray"];

NSLog(@"The Value of the Notification Array is : %u", saveValueOfArray.count)

}
```

Now i am having two issues with this piece of code.

1) The notification is sent only after the viewDidLoad in ViewController B has been called once, it does not work the first time.

2) Once it starts working, the notification sent gets incremented by 1 every time it is invoked

This is the console output when the notification was invoked the 4th time , it keeps going up everything it is called.

```
The Value of the Array is : 10
The Value of the Array is : 10
The Value of the Array is : 10
The Value of the Array is : 10
```

Can anyone please point out what the issue might be ?

Is there an easier way to pass the value of an array between two controllers

Comment: First off, you can always pass a parameter between view controllers by simply passing a parameter.  It can be on the init, or on some other procedure call, or you can set a property.  All you need is for A to create or be able to get the pointer to B.  But frankly your question doesn't make sense.  *Of course* the notification is only sent after you add the observer.  If you want the observer added earlier, add it in the init routine, or on some other call.  And "the notification sent gets incremented by 1 every time" is a meaningless statement without some context.

Comment: And your title is "NSNotification not being sent" but you then state it was received 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

this is a classic case of why you should not nest UIViewControllers. Its explained here in a much better way http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

(Assuming you are not using the addChildViewController method to nest your uiviewcontroller B.)

Instead of having a nested viewcontroller B, just use a UIView B, and add it as a subview to view controller A's view.

You have to figure out a better way to implement viewControllerB's viewDidLoad/Appear's functionality though.

Comment: did you read the link I posted in my answer? if you are doing [self.view bringSubviewToFront:controllerB.view] , then you have nested subviews.

Comment: sorry about that i misunderstood

Comment: The link sort of had a point some time ago (though even then I would not have agreed with it), but now it really does not have a point since you can have true child view controllers that the parent knows about and forwards on things like viewWillAppear.

Comment: I guess you are referring to my assumption in the answer? correct me if I am wrong, but I think, unless you add it as a childViewController, just adding a viewController's view as a subview, will screw up the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) The notification is sent only after the viewDidLoad in ViewController B has been called once, it does not work the first time

That's because that's where adding observer to that notification. If you want to observe earlier consider moving this code into init method.

> 2) Once it starts working, the notification sent gets incremented by 1 every time it is invoked

Every added observer wasn't removed. So those instances are continuing to be observer and processing. Consider removing the observer when the task is over.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem right that you put an UIViewController inside on another UIViewController, and your code is a "little" bizarre but well... since its friday and im in a good mood i will provide you a little example of posting notifications.

On the posting ViewController...

```
-(void)gettingValueOfArray:(NSArray*)newArray{

NSDictionary *storeArray = 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:newArray,@"newArray", nil];

[self postNotification:@"loadArray" withObject:storeArray];//calls postNotification

    }

-(void)sendNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
        [notification release];

}

-(void)postNotification:(NSString *)notification withObject:(id)obj{

NSNotification *n = [NSNotification notificationWithName:notification object:obj];
[n retain];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendNotification:) withObject:n waitUntilDone:NO];//calls sendNotification on the main thread        

}
```

On the Receiver ViewController...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(performDataLoad:)name:@"loadArray" object:nil];

}

//NOTE: if you want to receive only one notification at your ViewController B then remove the observer here

-(void)saveArray:(NSNotification *)n{

NSArray *saveValueOfArray = [[n object]objectForKey:@"newArray"];

NSLog(@"The Value of the Notification Array is : %u", saveValueOfArray.count)

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"loadArray" object:nil];


}

//Another NOTE: If you want multiples notifications then remove the observer once you are done with the class (i suppose that you in some point remove the subview) 

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidDisappear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"loadArray" object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since viewdidLoad function gets called every time view you push or add on a view.
So Each time Your object will be added to Notification center and increment the count of your notification call on your SecondViewController
So best place to put your add observer is to initWithnib function 
So Put your code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadArray:) name:@"loadArray" object:nil];
```

in `initWithNibName` function. and it will work as expected